# Writing Tables from Matlab into CSV

Tags: matlab, csv

I have several tables in **matlab** that and I would like to write all to one `.csv` file, vertically concatenating. I would like to keep the column names from each table as the top row, and would like to use a loop to write the csv. The ultimate goal is to read the data in to `R`, but `R.matlab` did not work well. Suggestions about how to do this?

Alternatively how can I change filenames in a for loop using the iterator?
e.g. along the lines of

```
for i=1:10
    writecsv('mydatai.csv',data(i))
end
```

So I must have at the end 10 csv files as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filename within the loop by using for sprintf string formatting function, for example:

```
dlmwrite(sprintf('mydata%i.csv', i), data(i) )
```

Note that the %i portion of the string is the sprintf formatting operator for an integer, it is just a coincidence that you also decided to name your iterator variable 'i'.

You can append extra data to an existing CSV by using the `dlmwrite` function, which uses a comma delimiter as the default, and including the '-append' flag.

Comment: dlmwrite works only on numeric data and does not accept tables as an input.

Comment: You are correct, I assumed the original question was using the term 'table' in a more general sense, as the table data type is relatively new to MATLAB, introduced in R2013b

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use

```
writetable(Table,filename )
```

and to change file name after every alternation you can use

```
filename = ['mydata' num2str(i) '.csv']
```